# moving div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to move div with javascript.Here is my code.

```
<body>
<input type="button" value="move right" onclick="moveRight()" />
<input type="button" value="move left" onclick="moveLeft()" />
<input type="button" value="move top" onclick="moveTop()" />
<input type="button" value="move bottom" onclick="moveBottom()" />
<div id="textDiv" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0">
my text        
</div>
</body>
```

my javascript code is

```
function moveRight()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("textDiv");
    var timer;
    timer = setInterval(function(){move(timer,elem,"top")},100);
}

function move(timer,elem,direction)
{
    alert(elem.offsetLeft);
    if(direction == "top" && elem.offsetLeft < 400)
    {
        elem.offsetLeft = elem.offsetLeft + 10 + "px";
        alert("offsetLeft is "+elem.offsetLeft);
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

Here first alert is showing 8px and second alert is also showing the same.How to move my div?

Answer (score 0):

use `position:absolute` and change `elem.style.top` (axis Y) or `elem.style.left` (axis X)

Comment: i changed position to absolute and changed javascript code to the following...                                                                                     function moveRight()
{
 var timer;
 move("top");
}                                                                                                                        function move(direction)
{
 var elem = document.getElementById("textDiv");
 if(direction == "top")
 {
  elem.style.left = (elem.style.left + 10) + 'px';
  setTimeout(function(){move("top"),500};
 }
}.....still it is not working

Comment: didn't see any change

Comment: can you give me your email,i will send my files

Answer (score 0):

Since you've set it as a `position:relative`, you'll want to use `elem.style.marginLeft`instead of `elem.offsetLeft`. Alternatively, you can set the position to absolute or fixed, if you don't want elements next to it to move.

Comment: i changed position to absolute and changed javascript code to the following... function moveRight() { var timer; move("top"); } function move(direction) { var elem = document.getElementById("textDiv"); if(direction == "top") { elem.style.left = (elem.style.left + 10) + 'px'; setTimeout(function(){move("top"),500}; } }.....still it is not working –

Answer (score 0):

You are tyring to modify value of offsetLeft which is `Readonly` and you cannot change its value.Alternatively you can change the values of `leftmargin' to make it move.

To use marginLeft check this fiddle. This is just the example of how you can use it. Each time you press moveleft it will increment the leftmergin
https://jsfiddle.net/eds9yfsq/6/

```
<script>

    function moveRight()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("textDiv");
    var left = elem.offsetLeft;
    var timer;
    move(timer,elem,"top", left);


}

function move(timer,elem,direction,left)
{


    if(direction == "top" && left  < 400)
    {
        elem.style.marginLeft  = left + 10 + "px"

    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

</script>

<input type="button" value="move right" onclick="moveRight()" />
<input type="button" value="move left" onclick="moveLeft()" />
<input type="button" value="move top" onclick="moveTop()" />
<input type="button" value="move bottom" onclick="moveBottom()" />
<div id="textDiv" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0">
my text        
</div>
```

For more details refer to the documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft